# How do I adjust the milestone markerType based on a custom field in AnyGantt?

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

How do I adjust the milestone markerType based on a custom field in AnyGantt?

I tried using this (where subType is the field name) but it renders a star.

```
timeline.milestones().markerType(
      function() {
        var customfieldSubType = this.getData('subType'); 
        if (customfieldSubType == "Strategy") {
          return "diamond";
        } else {
          return "circle";
        }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The *markerType()* function doesn't support callbacks. You can achieve the desired appearance by applying individual milestone settings right in the data. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/YrP9Noug/0) I prepared and pay attention to the milestone's data. This approach is described in [the documentation article](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Elements/Individual_Elements).